# if condition with auth() in laravel blade doesn't work

Tags: laravel, if-statement, conditional-statements, laravel-blade

I have an is_admin column in laravel users table and want to check if user is admin or not. See below code.

```
@if ({{ Auth::user()->is_admin }} == true)
    <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
    </li>
@endif
```

This error is coming up :
syntax error, unexpected '<' (View: C:\2020\lv02\lv02\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your code like this:

```
@if (\Auth::user()->is_admin == true)
    <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
    </li>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Its never mentioned in any documentation like that. Is it the best practice ?